# Adding views with IBAction to a NSStackView crashes application

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I want to use the NSStackView to stack views above each other, I also want them to de able to expand so I can't use the NSCollectionView if i understood it correctly.
So, in storyboard, I've created a NSStackView(embedded in scroll view) in the main view controller and a view controller that I want to fill it with:

[image: storyboard]

The button will fill the stack view with ten views:

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: NSStackView!

@IBAction func redrawStackView(_ sender: Any) {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        let stackViewItemVC = storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "StackViewItemVC") as! StackViewItemViewController
        stackViewItemVC.id = i
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(stackViewItemVC.view)
    }
}
```

And the ViewController on the right simply looks like this:

```
class StackViewItemViewController: NSViewController {
var id: Int = -1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    debugPrint("StackViewItemViewController" + id.description + "pressed")
}
```

Running this small application works fine, every time I press the button ten more stack view items appears. But, when I have the audacity to press one of the buttons to the right the application crashes:

[image: crash situation]

Where am I going wrong?
I have tried to work around the IBAction to verify that this what breaks, and the application will not crash if I subclass the button and make a "buttonDelegate" protocol with a function being called from mouseUp.

Comment: Don't you have a stacktrace in the debugger/console?

Comment: No, none is produced. Its really weird, usually a "Current stack trace:" is presented in the right column. But now its empty except for the blue (lldb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the `viewController` objects, which you create in the loop, are released immediately.

Even though the view is attached to the `stackView`, it's `viewController` is destroyed.

You can fix this issue by keeping a reference to each viewController.

You can do this by creating a new variable

```
var itemViewControllers = [StackViewItemViewController]()
```

and then add each newly created viewController to it:

```
itemViewController.append(stackViewItemVC)
```

Comment: That did the trick it seems! Thanks a million. I thought the reference from the button with the action was set automaticly from the storyboard,, but I guess that happens to late...

Comment: Glad I was able to help you! Do you mind accepting the answer?